# How do I apply this formula =COUNTA(D3:R3)/3 to all cells using ARRAYFORMULA In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to apply the above formula to all the rows in a single column, however, unable to do so since arrayformula takes range and so does counta.

I tried applying brackets over the counta({D3:D},{R3:R}) but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `BYROW()` function to apply it for all rows. What will be argument for `COUNTA()` function second cell then 3rd and on going?

Comment: Second cell would be D4:R4 and so on.

Comment: Please give a try to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BYROW()` function to iterate all rows and use other function to calculate per row result. Try-

```
=BYROW(D3:R,LAMBDA(rw,COUNTA(rw)/3))
```

Comment: This is working. How do I leave blank rows as blank? Now for blank rows its coming as 1.

Comment: @Prudhavi Try `=BYROW(D3:R,LAMBDA(rw,IF(INDEX(rw,1,1)="","",COUNTA(rw)/3)))`.